# How to make a horizontal stacked histplot based on counts?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart, histogram

I have a `df` which represents three states (`S1, S2, S3`) at 3 timepoints (`1hr, 2hr and 3h`r). I would like to show a stacked bar plot of the states but the stacks are discontinous or at least not cumulative. How can I fix this in `Seaborn`? It is important that time is on the y-axis and the state counts on the x-axis.

[image]

Below is some code.

```
data = [[3, 2, 18],[4, 13, 6], [1, 2, 20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['S1',  'S2', 'S3'])
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'Time'})
melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'Time')

plt.figure()
sns.histplot(data = melt,x = 'value', y = 'Time', bins = 3, hue = 'variable', multiple="stack")
```

EDIT:
This is somewhat what I am looking for, I hope this gives you an idea. Please ignore the difference in the scales between boxes...

[image]

Comment: I never thought I'd say this, but this might actually be an example of where drawing out what you want in MS paint and posting the image here might be helpful.

Comment: @Chris I improvised something in powerpoint. I hope this gets the idea across.

Comment: Maybe `sns.histplot(data=melt, y='Time', hue='variable', multiple="stack", weights='value', discrete=True)`?

Comment: @Johanc That worked like a charm, but I can't accept your answer because it is a comment...

Comment: You can accept @mwascom's answer, he implemented all this magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you want to use `value` as a weight:

```
sns.histplot(
    data=melt, y='Time', hue='variable', weights='value',
    multiple='stack', shrink=0.8, discrete=True,
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty tough in seaborn as it doesn't natively support stacked bars.  You can use either the builtin plot from pandas, or try plotly express.

```
data = [[3, 2, 18],[4, 13, 6], [1, 2, 20]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['S1',  'S2', 'S3'])
df = df.reset_index().rename(columns = {'index':'Time'})
# so your y starts at 1
df.Time+=1

melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars = 'Time')
# so y isn't treated as continuous
melt.Time = melt.Time.astype('str')
```

Pandas can do it, but getting the labels in there is a bit of pain.  Check around to figure out how to do it.

```
df.set_index('Time').plot(kind='barh', stacked=True)
```

[image]

Plotly makes it easier:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.bar(melt, x='value', y='Time', color='variable', orientation='h', text='value')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Its a pity that  there is no way of doing this in seaborn, because I created most of my plots in seaborn...

Comment: @JonnDough It can be done, it's just hard.  It's a process of layering plots on top of one another.  If you look for 100 percent stacked bar plots in seaborn there are examples.